Change Brave browser open new window "opens at full screen mode F11" preferences?
I'm trying to make brave browser open a new window in a maximized state (not full screen mode F11 mode) after it (unknown to me how) suddenly started to open new windows in minimized AND full screen mode (with brave-browser in bash) which is annoying because I have to do 3 more operation everytime I start a new brave window to prepare it which are

exit full mode with F11
Maximize the window
enter omnisearch bar (++ctrl+l++ search bar)

which is quite annoying.
Now I don't seem to find any settings for it in the Brave app "Settings" tab so I assume the edit'd have to be in the '~/.config/Brave-Browser/' in some file there but I'm now sure which...
any idea how to make brave new window open at "normal" screen mode with maximized window with the cursor already focused at the omnisearch bar ready to search?

did you try opening Brave minimised, drag it to the size you want then close it. Re-opening should remember the sizing thereafter.

Hmm yes it still enters full screen mode automatically and not maximized consistently.
I also tryed deleting "Brave-" folders in '~/.config/' and reopen it and it still full screens new windows.
It might have something to so with the ubuntu settings but I'm not sure which

Using Wayland, with v22.04 I opened Brave and clicked on the middle button (top right corner of Brave) to reduce the size of the window and dragged it to the size I wanted. I then closed it, reopened it and voila! it opened at the size I left it at. I then logged in an X11 session and it performed exactly the same way.

Yeah but "Maximized window" is not the main issue right now. It's the "Full screen mode" that is toggles with ++F11++  by default
